# Cache access in highly concurrent systems

Tags: asp.net, caching, concurrency

Suppose I have two threads(Thread1, Thread2) where the threads are accessing the cache for a given object such as in the code below nearly at the same time:

```
    Dim expensiveToGetData = Cache("ExpensiveDataKey")

    If ExpensiveToGetData is nothing then
'because the cache has expired

ExpensiveToGetData = LoadExpensiveDataFromDataSource()
       Cache("ExpensiveDataKey") = ExpensiveToGetData
    end If

    ProcessExpensiveData(ExpensiveToGetData)
```

**Isn't it possible for both threads to load the cache because they both requested data from the cache that was nothing/expired?  I've run some tests on a local machine and it seems that the cache is being loaded more than once.  Is this a normal pattern?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, using that code it is certainly possible that two different request will get Nothing from Cache, and therefore both reload data. If you want to avoid this, you need to synchronize the whole operation of getting the data.

One way to do synchronize access, would be to use code similar to:

```
Dim expensiveToGetData = Cache("ExpensiveDataKey")

If ExpensiveToGetData is nothing then
    SyncLock yourLockObject /* YourLockObject should be a Shared object. */
        expensiveToGetData = Cache("ExpensiveDataKey")
        If expensiveToGetData Is Nothing Then
            ExpensiveToGetData = LoadExpensiveDataFromDataSource()
            Cache("ExpensiveDataKey") = ExpensiveToGetData
        End If
    End SyncLock
end If

ProcessExpensiveData(ExpensiveToGetData)
```

The idea of checking whether we got the data before acquiring the lock, is to avoid excessive locking in an environment under high load. If it is not there, we need to check again once inside the lock, because another thread might have gotten the data while we were acquiring the lock.

Comment: Before you immediately reach for a lock to guard against the race condition, consider what the impact of calculating the cached value redundantly is when weighed against the cost of serializing access to a shared resource in a very parallel system.

That is, when you lock this cache, access to the cache from different threads (different page requests) will now queue up for the cached resource. In a web environment, you really need to think hard before going down this path because it will affect the number of requests you can service in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible, and it's not a desired pattern. As a quick fix you could establish a mutex lock on the cache as a quick fix, but ideally a better design would be to have the cache act as an intermediary load the expensive data itself. There is far more to that design pattern than I've alluded to, but it should get you started.